# How to tell which activity triggered resume

Tags: android

I am new to Android / Java but are progressing quite well.

I have hit a problem which I have searched using google and also in stack overflow but cannot find any related questions or answers.

In my onResume() and onPause() methods, how can I tell which activity was resumed from or initiated the pause ?

I need to know this so that I can decide what action to take, if for example the pause was caused by the system going to sleep, then I will do something, if it was caused by the camera being opened then I can do something else etc etc.

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(calling_name=='xxx') do something...
}
```

Comment: i think (and hope) there is no way to know it, it would compromise the user's privacy, don't you think?

Answer (score -1):

```
//full name of class ( with package name). e.g. com.example.app.MainActivity     
calling_name = this.getClass().getName();
```

or

```
//class name without package name. e.g. MainActivity
calling_name = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

Note that this refers to your current object.in your case instance of the Activity you are currently in.